# Generic keyword to reference the class when calling a static function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, this

I want to know if there is a generic keyword similar to **`this`** to reference the class when calling a static function from within a jQuery function for example like:

```
class MyClass {
    static FunctionA() {
        $('#someID').on('click', function() {
            this.FunctionB(); // Error here since 'this' here refers to the selected DOM element.
            MyClass.FunctionB(); // This works, but requires maintenance.
        });
    }

    static FunctionB() {
        this.FunctionC(); // Works here as 'this' refers to MyClass.
    }

    static FunctionC() {
    }
}

MyClass.FunctionA();
```

I basically want to know if we can somehow replace `MyClass.FunctionB();` with something that will be valid regardless if the class name changes?  Forgot to say that  I don't want to do `let classObject = this;` to use it for the call within the jQuery function.  That would be too easy.

Comment: Why not just use toplevel functions? I don't see the benefit of shoving them into the class as `static` methods.

Comment: I wanted to somehow contain those functions so that they are not all sitting global.  If there is a better way to "namespace" them in JavaScript, let me know.

Comment: If you’re using ES modules - and by now you probably should if your code is so complex as to require multiple namespaces - they won’t be global, but scoped to the module. AFAIK evergreen browsers can load them natively since like 2017; to target legacy browsers, you can use a bundler.

Comment: ES modules, ok, I'll look into that a bit more.

Comment: Why not just use `MyClass.FunctionB()` as the method invocation?  It's a static method.  Trying to treat it as a non-static method is a code smell.

Comment: If I change the class name, I have to also change any static function calls.

Comment: And?  How often does that happen?  Plus any competent form of IDE will make refactoring those things super easy

Comment: If I had to pick between having to make corrections myself or let the class take care of itself, I will pick the later always.  Why work when you don't have to.  Yes, it may just be a simply search and replace by us or the IDE, but it is still work.  Now imagine if you had 1000 classes to update the name.

Comment: You didn't answer the question of how often does that happen.  That's the main point here.  It is a lot of effort for an issue that just doesn't happen that often.  If you want to use static methods, use them.  If you want to use `this`, then don't make static methods.  As a general principle

Comment: In Swift, we have the `Self` keyword (with a capital 'S'), it may replace the class name (example: `Self.FunctionB( )` ); the `self` keyword (minor 's') is still reserved for instance functions. I' m looking for an equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Your anonymous funciton needs to be bound in order for it have the correct `this`

```
class MyClass {
    static FunctionA() {
      $('#someID').on('click', function () {
        this.FunctionB(); // Error here since 'this' here refers to the selected DOM element.
        MyClass.FunctionB(); // This works, but requires maintenance.
      }.bind(this));
    }

    static FunctionB() {
      this.FunctionC(); // Works here as 'this' refers to MyClass.
    }

    static FunctionC() {
      console.log('works')
    }
  }

  MyClass.FunctionA();
```

You can also make use of the `lexical this` functionality of arrow functions and you will have no need for bind

```
  class MyClass {
    static FunctionA() {
      $('#someID').on('click', () => {
        this.FunctionB(); // Error here since 'this' here refers to the selected DOM element.
        MyClass.FunctionB(); // This works, but requires maintenance.
      });
    }

    static FunctionB() {
      this.FunctionC(); // Works here as 'this' refers to MyClass.
    }

    static FunctionC() {
      console.log('works')
    }
  }

  MyClass.FunctionA();
```

Comment: ok, the lexical this method worked.  But how would I then reference in a generic way the DOM or jQuery element from that event?

Comment: I did not look too much into the .bind() function as it looks like it is now deprecated?

Comment: bind is not deprecated.  It is a method sitting on the function prototype that can give your function a permanent this.

If you wanted to reference the element, you can select it again using the jQuery function and call methods off of it.

Comment: The jQuery `bind()` is deprecated.  The javascript `bind()` is not. @NyaNguyen